# How to disable default popup for L.mapbox.featureLayer?

Tags: javascript, json, mapbox, geojson

When I create `L.mapbox.featurelayer` from `geojson url`, it automatically adds a popup with the name and description. How I can disable this?

Comment: Example of how your layer was created?

Comment: L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('data/fields-contour.json').addTo(map);

Comment: Try `L.mapbox.featureLayer({popupOptions: null}).loadURL('data/fields-contour.json').addTo(map);`

Comment: Error in `leaflet-src:6226` "Invalid GeoJSON object" (It cannot determinate `geometry.type` in `switch case` block)

Comment: So, post part of your code.